# Show a stochastic process is a martingale using Ito's lemma

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $W_t$ be standard Brownian motion. It is well known that $W_t^2-t$ is a martingale. One way to show this is by applying Ito's lemma to calculate that $d(W_t^2-t)/dt = 2W_t dW_t$, which has no drift. Therefore  $W_t^2-t$ is a martingale. I am a novice in stochastic process so I want to ask which theorems one use in this proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Itô's lemma you have :

$Y_t=W_t^2 - t= \int_0^t W_sdW_s$

So what you have here is that $Y_t$ is a local martingale. To prove that it is indeed a martingale it suffices to show that :

$\forall t>0, E[\langle Y\rangle_t]<\infty$

as you can check in [lemma 3](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/quadratic-variations-and-the-ito-isometry/) which is not too hard  I think.

Best regards

Comment: Added `\langle` and `\rangle` (hope you don't mind) and upvoted (hope you don't mind either...).

Comment: @ Did : It's ok as long as it is not a mathematical mistake in my post :-). Regards

Comment: why is $Y_t$ a local martingale?

Comment: @ mastro : Because : $\forall t>0, E[\langle Y\rangle_t]<\infty$ which is enough to show that $Y$ is a martingale (once an easy calculation is done). Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Corollary 3.2.6 in page 33 of [Oksendal's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=EQZEAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false), where the definition of $\mathcal{V}(0,T)$ is in page 25. So to  prove $\int_0^tW_sdW_s$ is a martingale, we can simply verify that $E(\int^t_0W_s^2ds)<\infty$, which is true since this integral is $\frac{1}{2}t^2$.